# Is it possible to use a @manytomany relation to only relate already existing objects in Database?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

My Scenario is a User which should get new Roles or lose them. I don't want to create a RelationEntitiy for the User, the Roles should be added to the User directly and then be saved via Spring Data Repository.

My Database Schema:

[image]

My Hibernate Relation in User Entity:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

But when I try to update it this way:

```
User user = new User("hansmeier", "password", "Hans", "Meier", 
"hansimeier@gmx.net", "+4915465656", roleRepository.findByName(Role.USER).orElse(null));
userRepository.save(user)
```

It tries to create the Role in the Database as well, but it already exists which causes an Error.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
detached entity passed to persist: app.model.Role; nested exception is 
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: 
app.model.Role
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are creating a new User and assign a role. What database error do you get?

Comment: Sure I added it to the main post now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not run in a transaction.

You have to add @Transactional to make sure that the fetch of the role and the save runs in the same transaction:

```
@Transactional
public void yourMethodName() {
    User user = new User("hansmeier", "password", "Hans", "Meier", 
        "hansimeier@gmx.net", "+4915465656", 
        roleRepository.findByName(Role.USER).orElse(null));
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but it causes Problems in my tests because it persist only at the end of the test method so I decided to move from CascadeType.ALL to only CascadeType.MERGE, because new Roles should only be created through my RoleService and it seem to work, but I'm currently running some test, so we will see

Comment: In your test you could call EntityManger.flush() to execute the SQL statements